# Prior knowledge in context of nullhypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, prior

I am currently working through the book [Doing Bayesian Data Analysis - John Kruschke](http://www.r-5.org/files/books/computers/algo-list/statistics/data-mining/John_K_Kruschke-Doing_Bayesian_Data_Analysis-EN.pdf) and have trouble to reason about a text paragraph [Page 315]

> Suppose that we are not flipping a coin, but we are flipping a flat-headed nail. In a social science setting, this is like asking a survey question about left or right handedness of the respondent, which we know is far from 50/50, as opposed to asking a survey question about male or female sex of the respondent, which we know is close to 50/50. When we flip the nail, it can land with its pointy tail touching the ground, an outcome I’ll call tails, or the nail can land balanced on its head with its pointy tail sticking up, an outcome I’ll call heads. We believe, just by looking at the nail and thinking of our previous experience with nails, that it will not come up heads and tails equally often. Indeed, the nail will very probably come to rest with its point touching the ground. In other words, we have a strong prior belief that the nail is tail-biased. Suppose we flip the nail 24 times and itcomes up heads on only 7 flips. Is the nail “fair”? Would we use it to determine which team gets to kick off at the Superbowl?

On the next page [page 316, same book] the author also states

> Suppose that the agreed prior for the nail is beta(θ|2, 20)...

So if we have the prior knowledge about the bias of the nail, what would prevent us from using this prior knowledge in context of NHST. Like for example using the probability of $P=0.2$ as the nullhypothesis in a binomial test? Why do we have to test the bias of the nail with $P=0.5$ as nullhypothesis?

I am fairly new to bayesian statistics so any explanation that helps me to understand the problem is welcome.

Comment: You definitely don’t have to test a null of $p=0.5$.

Comment: @Dave so the argument of the author would not valid then?

Comment: I don’t see a contradiction. Do you? // Kruschke is a member on here and once posted an answer to a question I had about his BEST paper, which was pretty cool!

Comment: @Dave Oh I see, the objective is to test the nail on `50/50 fairness`, i.e, we want to test if the nail land half of the time on head and half of the time on its tail. I somehow misunderstood that the objective would be to test the nail on `normal nail's fairness`, i.e., whatever probability a normal nail should land on its head.

Comment: I do not follow your comment, but if you un-confused yourself, splendid!